# Inequality in complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need help to prove that if $ \lvert z\rvert=1 $  then $\displaystyle \Bigg\lvert \frac{az+b}{\overline a\ + \overline b\ z} \Bigg\rvert =1$  .

Answer (score 2):

Since $\overline{z}\cdot z=|z|^2,\quad$ if $|z|=1,\quad$ then
$$|az+b|=|\overline{az+b}|=|\overline{az+b}||z|=|\overline{a}(\overline{z}\cdot z)+\overline{b}\cdot z|=|\overline{a}(1)+\overline{b}z|=|\overline{a}+\overline{b}z|$$

Answer (score 2):

Given $$\displaystyle |z| = 1\Rightarrow |z|^2=1\Rightarrow z \bar{z} = 1\Rightarrow z=\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$$

Now $$\displaystyle \left|\frac{az+b}{\bar{a}+\bar{b}z}\right| = \left|\frac{az+b}{\bar{a}+\bar{b}\times \frac{1}{\bar{z}}}\right| = \left|\frac{(az+b)|\bar{z}|}{\bar{az}+\bar{b}}\right| = |\bar{z}|\left|\frac{az+b}{\overline{az+b}}\right| = 1$$

above we have used $\displaystyle |z| = |\bar{z}|$ and $|az+b| = |\overline{az+b}|.$